# Splitting lines in txt. then Appending to two Lists. Makes double the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to append A text doc that has a name and email on each line 
(separated by a space) into two different lists. However instead of making two neat List with emails and names. It puts them into four lists.

```
def get_contacts(filename):
    name = []
    emails = []
    with open(filename, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')as contacts_file:
        line = contacts_file.readlines()
        for line in line:
            name.append(line.split()[0])
            emails.append(line.split()[1])
            print(name)
            print(emails)
    return name, emails
```

However, I get a return of:

```
['David']
['RandomEmail.com@Random.com']
[David:', 'John:']
[RandomEmail.com@Random.com', RandomEamil2.com@Random.com']
```

Comment: you have only two lists. Print after `for`-loop and you will see only two lists. Now you print() inside loop so you display the same two lists many times.

Comment: instead of using `print()` inside function you should do `a, b = get_contacts(filename)` and then `print(a, b)`

Answer (score 0):

Your function *returns* the value you expect, but you are printing on each iteration of the for loop, so you also see the building of the list in your console output.

```
def get_contacts(filename):
    name = []
    emails = []
    with open(filename, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as contacts_file:
        line = contacts_file.readlines()
        for line in line:
            name.append(line.split()[0])
            emails.append(line.split()[1])
    return name, emails


print(get_contacts("<filename>"))
```